# Google Cloud Storage Content-Type image/jpeg is invalid

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

When uploading an image to Google Cloud Storage using PHP createUploadUrl and option Content=type image/jpeg, I get an error logged as

```
"Invalid options supplied: Content-Type..."
```

This is the code:

```
$options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'mybucket', 'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg' ];
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload.php', $options);
```

The image is uploaded, but appears as binary/octet-stream files (GCS default). I have also tried mimeType and image/jpg. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the Content-Type as part of the context to move_uploaded_file(), not as part of the options to createUploadURL.

Comment: move_uploaded_file function (http://us2.php.net/move_uploaded_file) has only $filename and $destination as parameters, can you elaborate what you mean as part of the context?

Comment: Yeh i've jumped the gun slightly there - we're adding that in an upcoming release. For now, you can set the default context for 'gs' streams before you make the call to get the content-type passed through. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-default.php

Answer (score 0):

Once you upload a file(s) don't use **move_uploaded_file()** like most documentation shows, because it **looses the type information during the move**.

Even worse it ignores the **stream_context_create()** if you try to set it before move and sets type to default - **binary/octet-stream**.

Simply use **rename()** instead of **move_uploaded_file()**. The arguments in the brackets are the same.

If it helps here is my example.

Simple one:

```
foreach($_FILES['userfile']['name'] as $idx => $name) 
{     
    $original = $root_path . '/' . $name;;
    rename($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$idx], $original); 
}
```

Here is a more complicated one that forces the type (in case you want to):

```
foreach($_FILES['userfile']['name'] as $idx => $name) 
{     
    $original = $root_path . '/' . $name;
    $options = ['gs' => ['Content-Type' => $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$idx]]];
    stream_context_set_default($options);
    rename($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$idx], $original); 
}
```